# How do I change the nav ul li color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a navbar in my Page like this:

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="nav navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle"> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href=#>Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

When I apply this CSS:

```
.collapse ul li {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Isn't the `li` supposed to change color?

[image: the nav]

It's still the usual color. Why is this?

Comment: ```.collapse ul li a { color: #ffffff; }``` this will change the color of the text like Login.

Comment: @aavrug it will not. it hasn't. it never will...

Comment: Why? See, I have posted an answer below. If that is not working for you then definitely some other styling overriding your styling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to tweak your selectors

```css
.collapse ul.navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: red;
}

.collapse ul.navbar-nav>li {
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav role="navigation" class="nav navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href=#>Log In</a></li>
                    <li><a href=#>Sign Up</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is predefined background image property in bootstrap theme css

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff 0,#f8f8f8 100%)
```

This is preventing your background-color to apply.

So, Add `background-image:none;` to `.navbar.navbar-default.`

Comment: oh ok, I read the edit. but now i'm getting a big white background, I watt the color to change, not the background.

Comment: first apply background-image:none; and then color:(color);

Answer (score 0):

try to `a` tag change color to

```
.collapse ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for changing the color. If you want some other changes you can style it.

```css
.collapse ul li a {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="nav navbar-default">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" type="button" class="navbar-toggle"> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href=#>Log In</a></li>
      <li><a href=#>Sign Up</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: did you connect this document to bootstrap? you haven't, that's why it works for you and not me.

Comment: I was not suppose to connect it with bootstrap. I have just gave you the solution for your question that you asked and there was only this much of code without bootstrap and keep that in mind if you want to style any element and it's not applying then it means you have write more specific tag which will represent your tag.  :)

Comment: 'my question?' did you read the tags? I mean, couldn't you GUESS this was bootstrap? the `.classes` and all

Comment: Everyone have their own requirements so, if you are posting some question and then you want more specific answer then you should mention all the things that you need.